# DNS for Meteor Galaxy

Tags: meteor, dns, galaxy

Can someone explain to me how I need to configure my DNS settings using Galaxy and HTTPS? I obviously have no problem doing this on a provider with a static IP, but on Galaxy i just can't get it to work using DNSimple.

I want the following setup:
http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
https://example.com -> https://www.example.com
http:/www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com

Can someone please provide a TESTED and WORKING setup for this using FORCED HTTPS? Should i host my certificate on DNSimple or Galaxy? Should i add both domains on galaxy? What will my ALIAS and CNAME record be?

Im hosting on eu-west-1.galaxy-ingress.meteor.com .

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `http://` and `https://` are irrelevant to the DNS records, they are just telling your browser what protocol to use. `example.com` and `www.example.com` are two different Fully Qualified Domain Names (FQDNs), and both need A records to the static ip. So you would make a record on your root zone `@ IN A static-ips` (`@` means zone root so equivalent to `example.com. IN A static-ips`), and you would need a second record for www, `www. IN A static-ips`). This will make sure both go to the right ip

Now for the ssl certificate, the cert has to match the FQDN that the browser is trying to access, so if you only have a cert for `example.com`, then it will fail for `www.example.com`, if this is the case you can make a new cert with the common name `example.com`, and add the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) `www.example.com` to the cert during creation, this will make sure it works for both

If you want users who access `http://example.com` to go `https://example.com`, then that can't be done through DNS, server side or client side you will have to detect this and redirect to `https`, and depending on what you're using to host your app (e.g. apache, node, etc), there will be more documentation on that

Comment: I appreciate the effort. I have no problem setting up the desired result using static IP's. Its a whole different ballgame deploying on Meteor Galaxy as this does not have a static IP. Everything works now, except example.com wont redirect to www using https but apex domain without www.. Problem with Galaxy, its a domain, not an IP and apex domains etc require ALIAS/ANAME records etc. And redirect is done on Galaxy.

Comment: And Meteor support could not help me. They obviously don't have the answer either. Just keep pointing me to their documentation which i told them multiple times don't solve my problem.

Comment: I see, so you want your zone apex as a CNAME? That's generally tricky because like you said they need an alias, and that case have you tried making an alias record to take you apex to the galaxy FQDN, and a CNAME record for www. (`www. IN CNAME same.fqdn.as.alias`)? I still think the other two parts of my post are relevant as well, but let me know if they don't work out